# R-Package vegan Decorana

Tags: r-package, vegan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqeFn.png)I'm new to R and I was trying to run a Detrended correspondence analysis (DCA) which is a multivariate statistical analysis for ordination of species, I have four sites. I keep getting the error message:

```
> Error rowsums x must be numeric 

Species     Haasfontein Mini Pit    Vlaklaagte Mini Pit Vlaklaagte Block 3 Mini Pit Block 10 Mini Pit
Agrostis lachnantha 1   0   0   0
Aristida congesta subsp. Congesta   0   0   0   0
Brachiaria nigropedata  0   0   0   0
Cynodon dactylon    0   12  2   3
Cyperus esculentus  0   5   0   0
Digitaria eriantha  0   1   6   20
Elionurus muticus   0   0   0   0
Eragrostis acraea De Winter 0   0   1   0
Eragrostis chloromelas  35  0   12  4
Eragrostis curvula  6   0   0   0
Eragrostis lehmanniana  5   0   0   0
Eragrostis rigidior 3   0   1   0
Eragrostis rotifer  3   0   0   0
Eragrostis trichophora  10  1   2   2
Hyparrhenia hirta   0   0   9   1
Melinis repens  0   0   2   0
Panicum coloratum   0   4   0   0
Panicum deustum     3   0   0   0
Paspalum dilatatum  0   0   0   0
Setaria sphacelata var. sphacelata  0   1   0   0
Sporobolus africanus    0   0   2   0
Sporobolus centrifuges  1   0   1   0
Sporobolus fimbriatus   0   0   0   0
Sporobolus ioclados 2   0   5   1
Themeda triandra    0   0   0   0
Trachypogon spicatus    0   0   0   0
Tragus berteronianus    0   0   0   1
Verbena bonariensis 16  0   2   0
Cirsium vulgare 0   0   0   0
Eucalyptus cameldulensis    1   0   0   0
Xanthium strumarium 0   0   0   0
Argemone ochroleuca 0   0   0   0
Solanum sisymbriifolium 0   0   0   0
Campuloclinium macrocephalum    7   0   0   0
Paspalum dilatatum  0   0   0   0
Senecio ilicifolius 0   0   0   0
Pseudognaphalium luteoalbum (L.)    8   0   0   0
 Cyperus esculentus     0   0   0   0
Foeniculum vulgare  0   0   0   0
Conyza canadensis   0   0   0   1
Tagetes minuta  0   0   0   0
Hypochaeris radicata    0   0   0   0
Solanum incanum 0   0   0   0
Asclepias fruticosa 11  0   0   0
Hypochaeris radicata    0   0   0   0
```

My data is organised as shown above and I'm not sure if my data is organised correctly or there is some other error. Can someone please assist me

Comment: It would be better to show your data in text form as part of the question. Add your clarification to the question instead of writing a comment. Describe what exactly you are doing to get the error. If you have code, show it.

Comment: Hi Bodo I attached an image because when I paste the data it does not look the way it looks in the table. What I'm doing is running a Detrended correspondence analysis (DCA) using this data that I have imported using the read.xls command. I don't know how else to explain further because like I said I just started teaching myself R a few days ago so I'm using tutorials for the code

Comment: Add your clarification **to the question** instead of writing comments. To get the table look better you can format it as a code block by indenting all lines with 4 spaces. I think you don't have to show all lines. You could remove some lines and write `...` instead.

Comment: @Bodo Sorry but I'm not a coder so I don't really know how to do what you're asking, I'm new to both R and this platform, I just came here for help because I just started using R like 2 days ago

Comment: So **you** say that your data have four columns. What does **R** say? Ask this with `ncol(mydata)` (and put the name of your data set in place of `mydata`). Quite clearly, you have non-numeric data, as computer says so (and in these cases computers is always correct). Because you have (or should have) much fewer columns than rows, you can try to identify which columns have non-numeric data. Function `summary(mydata)` should give you that information: if you get numerical summaries on quantiles etc, the variable is numeric. Check how to read in your data.

Comment: PS. After you get your data cleaned to be all numeric, you will have two obvious problems, but try to make the data numeric first.

Answer (score 2):

You're still fighting to get you data into **R**. That is your first problem. After you tackle this problem and manage to read in your data, you have the following problems:

1. You should not have empty (all zero) rows in your data, but they will give an error (empty columns are removed and only give a warning).
2. DCA treats rows and columns non-symmetrically, and you should have species as columns and sampling units as rows. You should transpose your data (function `t()`).
3. You really should not use DCA with only four sampling units. It will be meaningless.

I think the last point is most important.